# Jenkins Pipeline Docker Agent Setup Dynamically

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In declarative pipelines we set up docker agent as below,

```
pipeline {
  agent {  
   docker {
    image dockerImage
    args dockerArgs
    registryUrl dockerRegistryUrl
    registryCredentialsId dockerRegistryCredentialsId
    label dockerLabel
    alwaysPull true
   }
  }
....
```

but I want to do something like this,

```
def dockerAgent = new Docker(dockerImage, dockerArgs,...)

pipeline {
 agent {  
    dockerAgent
    }
}
....
```

The intention is to generate **Docker Agent** with the properties using a **shard-lib**
and inject the agent to the pipeline. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Appreciate follow up as I ran into same issue to no avail.

Comment: Also looking for some advice on this one.

Comment: Seems this is not possible then?